# Deleting cache cookie for chrome using shortcut

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to simulate the shortcut for deleting cache/cookies for chrome using java robot class methods. I does not work for key combination SHIFT+Ctrl+e. Why does this not working? Is it a security reason or my coding error?

Code snippet:

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly as per my info we need : CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE to do this task

```
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(5000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
        robot.delay(100);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

But why to complicate it, use inbuilt functions:

```
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was mistyping.

I tried the code you provided earlier but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

to delete all your cookies